# syn match don't work in vimrc

Tags: syntax-highlighting, vim, highlighting

If I added to my vimrc this

```
highlight whitespaceEOL term=reverse ctermbg=Grey guibg=Grey
syntax match whitespaceEOL /\s\+$/
autocmd! filetype zsh,sh,python,vim,c,cpp syntax match ColorColumn /\%>80v.\+/
```

don't work, only work if I make

```
syntax clear
```

but I lost other syntax

Answer (score 1):

you may want to look into the `contained`  and `contains` keyword.
try adding `contained=ALL`   at the end ef syntax match lines.

Comment: the first case work with `autocmd Syntax * syn match whitespaceEOL /\s\+\(\%#\)\@!$/ containedin=ALL`

Comment: and the second with `autocmd! filetype zsh,sh,python,vim,c,cpp syn match ColorColumn /\%>80v.\+/ containedin=ALL` ... why the difference ?

Comment: and when I save the file `:w` , I lost the syn added

Comment: may be having something to do with the order in which `.vimrc` and the syntax files are read in.  it might be that the `c.vim` syntax file is overriding the setting.  try putting it in `.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`  btw, i do not understand where to add contains or contained.  i use the classic method of trial-and-error :)

Comment: Putting it on `.vim/after/syntax/c.vim` didn't work for me.

Comment: Actually it did, for others that might be lost as I was, `.vim/after/syntax/c.vim` is for the `c` language, so make sure to create the right file for the programming language you are using, in my case what worked was: `.vim/after/syntax/go.vim`

Comment: @alvin maybe you could update your answer to include this part about `after/syntax`